How to run SCOPE scripts in ADF with C# nuget
Looking at the documentation I see no example of how to run this script against ADLS instance; is there an example of what activity type etc. should be used for this functionality?

You can use Custom activity in ADF to achieve your requirement.

First create a storage account and upload your script file to a location in the storage account.

Create an Azure batch  and create required pools in it.

Now, create Azure batch linked service in ADF.


Give this linked service to the Custom activity in ADF. In the settings, give the uploaded script file location from storage account. For this, you need to create an Azure Blob storage linked service.



Now, run the custom activity and your script from storage account will be executed. You can go through this reference documentation to know more about this.
